# CiviCRM - WordPress - Frequent timeout errors

Tags: wordpress

I have CiviCRM installed on a development WordPress site and I keep having problems with timeout errors. This is a VPS server with a VPS SQL account. The server has 2000MB of RAM and the SQL account has another 500MB of RAM. This is the only website running on this VPS. I have configured PHP to have a memory limit of 300MB and a max execution time of 500. I have confirmed in WordPress that these settings are recognized by WordPress. I'm trying to figure out what to do next to troubleshoot what needs to be adjusted to address the timeout errors. CiviCRM version 5.44.0. WordPress version 6.0.1

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a billion reasons for WP/Civi timeouts. To start from, a few notes:

- **300MB PHP RAM**: I'd make it 512Mb or 1G:  the latter requires at least 4G on the server
- **500Mb SQL RAM**: well, it's actually not that much: try this https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl to check DB internals: it worth following recommendations the script provides.
- **max execution time of 500** : afraid this one does not make sense nor any difference here at all. You might want to stick to 120.

Also, have you checked:

- CiviCRM Logs
- WP Debug output
- PHP error logs
- Web server [Apache?] error logs
- MySQL error logs?

Your answer is somewhere in the logs above.

Comment: Thank you, yurg. This at least points me in the right direction. I'm marking your answer as "accepted," not because all my problems have suddenly been fixed but because your answer is at least helping me figure out what to focus on.

Comment: Thank you @BruceHooke, please keep us updated if possible: maybe someone else will find your follow-up useful ;-)